Add Sheets File to Gmail draft as "panel"
I create an email draft with the following code, referenced here.
GmailApp.createDraft('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see attached file.', {attachments: ???});

I want to add a Sheets file to my email draft. But not as a plain URL or hyperlink but as this "panel" like when you insert files manually using "Insert files using Drive":


Is there any option to include the Sheets file in a draft with the function GmailApp.createDraft() with this "panel" view?

Perhaps this could be done with a .gsheet file?

Yes, I mean a file created with Google Sheet, so .gsheet file. But this "panel" view is available for files from Google Slides or Docs as well

Are you asking if Gmail Service has a method for this? In case that doesn't exists, are you open to use a workaround/ hack ?

Yes, question is if it is possible to add a Google Sheet / Slides / Docs file as this "panel" view programmatically with Apps Script

Have you tried defining the file first like var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("File Name"); and then attach it by using attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]?

Yes sure, but I dont want to attach the Sheets file as pdf and if I use Google Sheets as MimeType it is not working

A "panel" shows a hyperlink to a file hosted in Google Drive. This method is not exclusive to Google Sheets files; it is used for any file hosted in Google.
AFAIK, Google Apps Script doesn't include a method to insert a file from Drive in the same way that the user interface does. Please bear in mind that the Gmail Service and even the Gmail API do not cover all the Gmail features available through the Gmail apps (web, Android, iOS).
Considering this, you could opt to craft the panel using HTML by yourself, considering the restrictions for email.
To learn how to create a draft, insert one or more files from Drive of the type that interests you, then send the file to yourself, then use web browser tools like View source code or Inspect to examine the code used to display the "panels" on the message that you received.
